# Return exception errors as JSONs in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

This morning I was developing my Django REST API with Tastypie when I encountered a problem I don't know how to solve. 
I have a Resource that looks like this:

```
class UserSignUpResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        object_class = User
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        include_resource_uri = False
        resource_name = 'newuser'
        serializer = CamelCaseJSONSerializer(formats=['json'])
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=UserSignUpForm)
```

This Resource receives JSON-formated data and creates a new Resource (I only  permmit POST ops). So, first the data is checked through the:

```
validation = FormValidation(form_class=UserSignUpForm)
```

The thing is, that if data is incorrect, it does return a **ImmediateHttpResponse**. But I would want to capture this exception and create a JSON like this:

```
{"status": False, "code": 777, "errors": {"pass":["Required"], ...}
```

So, I override my **wrap_view** and add the following code snippet:

```
except ImmediateHttpResponse, e:
    bundle = {"code": 777, "status": False, "error": e.response.content}
    return self.create_response(request, bundle, response_class = HttpBadRequest)
```

This code captures the exception properly, but it has a problem. **e.response** contains a unicode string with the errors. So, the response it finally gives is

```
{"code": 777, 
"error": "{\"birthdayDay\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"birthdayMonth\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"birthdayYear\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"csrfmiddlewaretoken\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"email\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"email_2\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"firstName\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"gender\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"lastName\": [\"This field is required.\"], 
         \"password1\": [\"This field is required.\"]}", 
"status": false}
```

That damned \ and the first " are killing me. On the other side, the Frontend developer, who is working with AJAX, tells me that he can't parse the errors.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Does anybody knows how to convert the exception response, into a JSON?

Comment: `e.response.content` seems to be a string rather than a dictionary. Which is why the JSON serializer handles it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to send the response content as json, not as a serialized json string:

```
import json
bundle = {"code": 777, "status": False, "error": json.loads(e.response.content)}
```